# Change mac scroll direction in mouse and not touchpad

Tags: macos, mouse, macos-monterey, touchpad

On MacOs Monterey 12.1
The scroll direction is shared with the touchpad and the mouse.

I would like the touchpad to be netural and mouse to not be.

I tried some applications like mos and they did not do it.
I know I can create an app to do it myself, but I really hope there are some answer for it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've had this exact frustration for two years and finally did a search and found a solution.

From this Apple discussion page (https://discussions.apple.com/thread/6931667), I found ScrollReverser (https://github.com/pilotmoon/Scroll-Reverser/releases/tag/v1.8.2), which installed in a second and works as soon as you set the Preferences for it.

Hope it helps you too.